# There has been a runner system failure, please try again

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

[image]

How to resolve this error specially on macbook. I have installed docker on my machine also but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start docker deamon on your gitlab runner.

Below is link to docker desktop for mac.
If you start docker desktop gui, docker deamon will start.

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not just for mac computers but also for windows. I experienced this problem and found out that the the PowerShell script part for Infra as Code that I was using was not installing docker.

I therefore made changes to the Infra as Code to ensure that Microsoft-Hyper-V is enabled and that docker is actually installed and docker service started, then the computer HAS to be restarted for the changes to pick up.

I do not know the exact order of when the restart should happen since I am still understanding the flow but I can update my answer when I have more info